# bootstrap 4 table is not responsive on mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

I have a bootstrap 4 responsive table coded as below. It is not responsive when I open the page on mobile. the page works fine when I open it on Desktop and reduce the browser screen size.
Please help. 
Note - I also tried adding table-responsive-lg etc, to be more specific but it doesnt work either.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-success">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Block</th>
            <th scope="col">Flat#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Ocassion</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% var newItems, totalAmt = 0; %>
        <% var len = newItems.length; %>

          <% for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) { %>
            <% var sNo = i+1; %>

            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><%= sNo %></th>
                <td><%= newItems[i].block %></td>
                <td><%= newItems[i].apt %></td>
                <td><%= newItems[i].name %></td>
                <td><%= newItems[i].email %></td>
                <td>₹ <%= newItems[i].amt %></td>
                <td><%= newItems[i].occasion %></td>
                <td class="td-actions text-left">
                  <button type="submit" formaction="/edit" rel="tooltip" name="editBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-round btn-sm" value=<%= newItems[i]._id %>>
                      <i class="material-icons md-18">edit</i>
                  </button>
                  <button type="submit" formaction="/delete" rel="tooltip" name="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-round btn-sm"value=<%= newItems[i]._id %>>
                      <i class="material-icons md-18">close</i>
                  </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <% totalAmt = totalAmt + newItems[i].amt; %>
          <% }; %>
          <tr>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <th class="text-right">Total</th>
            <th>₹ <%= totalAmt %></th>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: can you share a working snippet which replicates this issue?

Comment: I have given the code snippet. When I try this in desktop it is responsive but not in mobile.

Comment: Hi @Ashok, you'd have to include a working code with filled data so that we can see it working and then advise on corrections